# exit code of diff

Tags: command-line, diff

If I run `diff -q` on two files and they are identical, the exit code generated by `echo $?` is `0`; if the files differ, the exit code is `1`. Why is that? In what way is the first `diff` a success and the second a failure?

I used the terms "success" and "failure" based on my reading and limited understanding of http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals:

> 1. Exit Status
>      Every command results in an exit code whenever it terminates.
>      This exit code is used by whatever application started it to evaluate
>      whether everything went OK. This exit code is like a return value from
>      functions. It's an integer between 0 and 255 (inclusive). Convention
>      dictates that we use 0 to denote success, and any other number to denote
>      failure of some sort. **The specific number is entirely application-specific**,
>      and is used to hint as to what exactly went wrong.

I should have read `man diff` right to the end where the convention used by the developers is clear.

Comment: The real question is: when running `diff`, is finding a difference a success or a failure?

Comment: Neither a success nor a failure, but a bit of information to be used in further processing. `diff` can be used to answer "Is this file the same as that file?" Where is the "success" in that?

Comment: FWIW, think why 0 is success and non-zero, including 1, is failure - there is (usually) only one successful outcome, but many failure conditions. Similarly, two files can be non-differing in only one way - the contents are identical, but differ in any number of ways.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From `man diff`:

> Exit status is 0  if inputs are the same, 1 if different, 2 if trouble.

I freely admit this might not be [completely standard](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) but exit codes are *more what you'd call "guidelines" than actual rules*.

[image]

In this case, deviating from the standard allows you to easily run `diff` in scripts.

```
diff a b && echo "no difference" || echo "differences!"
```

This is similar to `grep` which will exit 0 is something is found, and 1 if something isn't found. I can't explain the orientation between 0 and 1 for `diff`. I assume they went with C-standard boolean outcomes.

It doesn't really matter. It's just an arbitrary number.

Comment: Sadly this is more like `|| echo "differences! OR something failed fatally; you'll never know which."`, for example if one of the input files is missing, it'll think of it as a "difference", even though it's an actual error. Similar for unreadable inputs, etc.

Answer (score 7):

`man diff` tells us

EXIT STATUS

```
   The following exit values shall be returned:

    0     No differences were found.

    1     Differences were found.

   >1     An error occurred.
```

Your calling the exit values "success" and "failure" is a self-limiting choice.Programs have a whole 8 bits for exit status, values from 0 to 255.

Comment: Technically, exit stati can be negative (which often means killed by a signal with number `- exit status`.)