# How to capture and reuse diff result?

Tags: command-line, bash

Using  Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa) `diff` (GNU diffutils) 3.7

From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698784/exit-code-of-diff) we have:

```
diff a b && echo "no difference" || echo "differences!" ;
```

If `diff a b` has exit code of 0 then said differently we have a match (all ok, Success, same inputs, no difference between a b).

How to capture the result of diff with text "`no difference`" and use it later in the script? How to reuse result "`no difference`"?

Reuse result, like a screen message:

> The result from diff a b = "`no difference`"

Or

> The result from diff a b = "`Same inputs.  Match.  All ok.  No difference.  Success.` "

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

If you want a quick confirmation, that the files match, use the option `-s`,

```
diff -s file1 file2
```

### Longer answer

I assume that you want to learn how to create a shellscript, so I suggest that you start with the following one,

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! test -f "$1" || ! test -f "$2"
then
 echo "
Usage $0 <file1> <file2>

to check if <file2> and <file2> differ
and do some more operations"
 exit 1
fi

diff "$1" "$2"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]  # testing exit status ( 0 <--> match )
then
 match=true
else
 match=false
fi

# maybe several other commands here ...

if $match
then
 echo "Same inputs.  Match.  All ok.  No difference.  Success. "
else
 echo "The files are different"
fi
```

Later on you can start modifying it (making it simpler or more complicated)

Answer (score 0):

Using answer provided by sudodus ... with minor changes.

Both scripts work, #1 by sudodus above and #2 below.

In script #2 below, are Lines ending with `;`
Is the  `;` to be deleted?

background
src1 is Source directory = /media/u3/usb2_drive
dest is Destination directory = /media/u3/d_driveHDD/test
script below is in part 26 thus match26

````
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; # testing exit status ( 0 <--> match ) No differences echo $? = exit code = 0 ;  
then  
 match26=true ;  
else  
 match26=false ;  
fi ;  


if $match26 ;  
then  
 tput setaf 12 ; echo "diff -rq S D =" |tr '\n' ' ' ;   
 tput sgr0     ; echo "Match.  Same inputs.  All ok.  No difference.  Success. " ;  
else  
 echo "Differences were found. ________________________________________ dirs differ" ;  
fi ;```
````

Comment: In `bash` you can use semicolon the separate commands on the same line. If you put a semicolon at the end of a line it will make no difference, because a new-line is a separator between commands, unless you put a backslash. So in order to have really long commands in `bash` easily seen in an editor, you can 'line-break it with backslashes'.