# How to fix side-effect surrounding diff script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa) and diff (GNU diffutils) 3.7

History at:
[How to capture and reuse diff result?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416924/how-to-capture-and-reuse-diff-result)

While testing this script below ...
Two directories were made different by
changing one Letter in file name from
abc.txt to Abc.txt  capital A

script works and says:

```
diff -rq src1/ dest/  Differences were found. ________________________________________ dirs differ
```

script is:

```
src1='/media/u3/usb_stick' ; dest='/home/u3/Music/x' ;   
diff -rq "$src1/" "$dest/" ; 
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; # testing exit status ( 0 <--> match ) No differences echo $? = exit code = 0 ; 
then
 match21=true ; 
else
 match21=false ; 
fi ; 
echo ; 
if $match21 ; 
then
 tput setaf 12 ; echo "diff -rq "src1/" "dest/" " |tr '\n' ' ' ; 
 tput sgr0     ; echo "Match.  Same inputs.  All ok.  No difference.  Success. " ; 
else
 echo "diff -rq "src1/" "dest/"  Differences were found. ________________________________________ dirs differ" ; 
fi ;
```

But then there is a problem ...
when the diff command is commented out `#`
the result is incorrect:

```
diff -rq src1/ dest/  Match.  Same inputs.  All ok.  No difference.  Success.
```

above result is incorrect.

commented out `#` script is

```
src1='/media/u3/usb_stick' ; dest='/home/u3/Music/x' ; 
# diff -rq "$src1/" "$dest/" ; 
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; # testing exit status ( 0 <--> match ) No differences echo $? = exit code = 0 ; 
then
 match21=true ; 
else
 match21=false ; 
fi ; 
echo ; 
if $match21 ; 
then
 tput setaf 12 ; echo "diff -rq "src1/" "dest/" " |tr '\n' ' ' ; 
 tput sgr0     ; echo "Match.  Same inputs.  All ok.  No difference.  Success. " ; 
else
 echo "diff -rq "src1/" "dest/"  Differences were found. ________________________________________ dirs differ" ; 
fi ;
```

How to fix side-effect surrounding diff script?

This means when not running diff, commented out #

```
# diff -rq "$src1/" "$dest/" ;
```

then have no message or
show a minus sign, a filler:

```
-
```

as a message.

Answer (score 0):

```
src1='/media/u3/usb_stick' ; dest='/home/u3/Music/x' ; 
# diff -rq "$src1/" "$dest/" ; 
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ...
```

Here youŕe checking the `$?` after setting `$dest` => $? is `0`, unless there is an error.
So not an "side effect".

Comment: How to have a script with a third option?  1. diff exit code=0=dirs Match  2. diff exit code=1=directories are different (differs)  3. Not run diff or bypass 15 Lines of script, means no output from 15 Lines of script or output is a minus sign ```-```  .

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Might be you're best off by starting with a study of the Bash guides at www.tldp.org - maybe begin by looking up `if - then`, `select` and `case` in there.